# Multiprocessing storing read-only string-array for all processes

Tags: python, mapreduce, python-multithreading, python-3.6

I am trying to create workers for a task that involves reading a lot of files and analyzing them.

I want something like this:

```
list_of_unique_keys_from_csv_file = [] # About 200mb array (10m rows)
# a list of uniquekeys for comparing inside worker processes to a set of flatfiles
```

I need more threads as it is going very slow, doing the comparison with one process (10 minutes per file).

I have another set of flat-files that I compare the CSV file to, to see if unique keys exist. This seems like a map reduce type of problem.

main.py:

```
def worker_process(directory_glob_of_flat_files, list_of_unique_keys_from_csv_file):
  # Do some parallel comparisons "if not in " type stuff. 
  # generate an array of
  # lines of text like : "this item_x was not detected in CSV list (from current_flatfile)"
  if current_item not in list_of_unique_keys_from_csv_file:
     all_lines_this_worker_generated.append(sometext + current_item)
  return all_lines_this_worker_generated




def main():   
    all_results = []
    pool = Pool(processes=6)
    partitioned_flat_files = [] # divide files from glob by 6
    results = pool.starmap(worker_process, partitioned_flat_files, {{{{i wanna pass in my read-only parameter}}}})
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    all_results.extend(results )
    resulting_file.write(all_results)
```

I am using both a linux and a windows environment, so perhaps I need something cross-platform compatible (the whole fork() discussion).

**Main Question: Do I need some sort of Pipe or Queue, I can't seem to find good examples of how to transfer around a big read-only string array, a copy for each worker process?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just split your read-only parameters and then pass them in. The `multiprocessing` module is cross-platform compatible, so don't worry about it.

Actually, every process, even sub-process, has its own resources, that means no matter how you pass the parameters to it, it will keep a copy of the original one instead of sharing it. In this simple case, when you pass the parameters from main process into sub-processes, `Pool` automatically makes a copy of your variables. Because sub-processes just have the copies of original one, so the modification cannot be shared. It doesn't matter in this case as your variables are read-only.

But be careful about your code, you need to wrap the parameters you need into an
 iterable collection, for example:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

pool = Pool()
results = pool.starmap(add, [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
print(results)
# [3, 7]
```

Comment: yeah but the main issue I'm having is, EACH process/thread everything, needs to get the SAME global read-only `list_of_unique_keys_from_csv_file` array... However, when I try to print out what we got inside the process, it appears it has chunked/divided up the array or something. This is not what I want. I want the ORIGINAL array copied across all threads / all processes. Maybe I need to read the main file inside each worker, but I feel it would be silly to have 200 workers reading the exact same file at startup (so instead my main thread reads it then copies the array to all)

Comment: @Dexter That's easy, `results = pool.starmap(func, [(one_file, list_of_unique_keys_from_csv_file) for one_file in partitioned_flat_files])`

Comment: Yeah that worked, I wonder why the itertools way doesn't work. Thanks.